# Change of section display upon selection of grade

Tags: jquery

There are grades 7-10 from the first combo box and the second combo box contains the section per grade. What I want to achieve is when the user selects 7 as the grade for example, the second combo box will change its contents and display the available section for grade 7. Any tips on how to achieve this? I know this has something to do with onchange event.
.

Comment: Its a bit of a broad question, may need to elaborate on it a bit more. Such as where are you getting the data and Is it purely a Javascript solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p32n23pk/)
As no further details provided by you, i am just mapping the value of the combobox with an javascript array on the **change event** of the **combobox**

my initial html was

```
 <select id="grade">
   <option value=""></option>   
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select> 
 <select id="mapping">

</select>
```

where **grade** is source and **mapping** is target

my jquery code is

```
$(function(){
    $("#grade").change(function(){
        var selectedvalue = $(this).val();
        var listofvalues =[{"text":"seven","value": "7"},{"text": "eight","value":"8"},{"text": "nine","value" :"9"},{"text" : "ten","value" : "10"}];
        var filter = $.grep(listofvalues,function(item){
                   return item.value == selectedvalue;
        });   
        $('#mapping').html('');
        //console.log(filter);
        $.each(filter,function(i,item){
        $('#mapping').append('<option value="'+ item.value +'">'+ item.text +'</option>');
        });



    });


});
```

Hope it helps